# How to show different column in select field django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've a model Customer:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.customer_name
```

Customer Model is related with Event and CustomerEvent Model by ForiegnKey.
In Django Admin panel we like to show `customer_name` in dropdown with Event which is working fine as **Customer** object str representation is `self.customer_name`.
But In **CustomerEvent** we'd like show `contact_name` in admin panel dropdown which is not in `__str__` representation.

Here is my sample code:

```
def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
         context['adminform'].form.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(customer_type__iexact='I')
         return super(CustomerEventAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Please give me some idea to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer:

I just override `formfield_for_foreignkey` method and now it's looking like:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'customer':
            formfield.label_from_instance = lambda obj: obj.contact_name
        return formfield
```